# Acf field present but i can't get it on my front - REST API wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I have a problem very strange with the REST API wordpress. I use the two plugins ACF Field and ACF-TO-REST-API. I had 2 field for posts type.
When i put my wordpressUrl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/323 i get its like a charm :

[image]

But when i get with axios on my front and when i console.log(data.acf) I have only the first fied... Th other (and others : I tried with severals fields) are disapear.
[image]

Who it's possible ?

Thanks for your helps